# is there an easy way to go from shape outline to openGL matrix?

Tags: opengl, 2d

I was wondering if there where a way of "tracing" an outline of a shape easily?

For instance this is code to draw a star

```
static GLfloat starVertices [] = {0.0, 0.25f,
                                   0.1f, 0.1f,
                                   0.25f, 0.08f,
                                   0.15f, -0.05f,
                                   0.25f, -0.25f,
                                   0.0, -0.125f,
                                   -0.25f, -0.25f,
                                   -0.15f, -0.05f,
                                   -0.25f, 0.08f,
                                   -0.1f, 0.1f};
```

is there a easy way to produce code for shape like http://bit.ly/xrImhI for instance (if its cleaned up)?

id be cutting the detail out just keeping the outline (using a texture ontop and cutting the image so each has a septate function (eg head, eyes, mouth, nose, etc) and them combining them with a Hierarchical model.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a [raster to vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_raster_to_vector_conversion_software) routine.  OpenGL won't help you there.